# What is the difference between `@Bind` and `@BindView` in butterknife?

Tags: android, inject, butterknife

I Just started using butterknife.
In the project, colleagues using butterknife, version is 7.0.0.

I saw him write `@Bind(R.id.tv_name)`.
But I see butterknife official website butterknife version is 8.0.1, syntax is `@BindView(R.id.tv_name)`

Is syntax changed ? or both can be used ? or something else ?
What is the difference between them ?

I not find the answer on the Internet
I hope everyone's help, thx !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, the syntax changed in the version 8.0.

You can check the changelog here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2016-04-25 to see al the changes. But from 7.X to 8.X the changelog is:

> - `@Bind` becomes `@BindView` and `@BindViews` (one view and multiple views, respectively).
> - Calls to `bind` now return an `Unbinder` instance which can be used to `null` references. This replaces
>     the `unbind` API and adds support for being able to clear listeners.
> - New: `@BindArray` binds `String`, `CharSequence`, and `int` arrays and `TypeArray` to fields.
> - New: `@BindBitmap` binds `Bitmap` instances from resources to fields.
> - `@BindDrawable` now supports a `tint` field which accepts a theme attribute.
> - The runtime and compiler are now split into two artifacts.
>      `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'`
>      `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'`
> - New: `apply` overloads which accept a single view and arrays of views.
> - ProGuard rules now ship inside of the library and are included automatically.
> - `@Optional` annotation is back to mark methods as being optional.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts ! : )

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the only difference between those keywords is that `@Bind` was renamed to `@BindView` in v8.0.0.

Please note that `ButterKnife.unbind()` was removed, and replaced with an `Unbinder` that's returned by `bind()` so that no external view references are retained.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer