# butterknife 8.8.1 : Plugin with id 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

i'am having an issue with my project every time i'm trying to run it the error Plugin with id 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' not found.  shows up
can someone tell me whats going on with this code ??
i'am stuck and any help is appreciated 
here is the gradle

```js
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        flavorDimensions "default"
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
dependencies {
   final SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '27.0.2'
    final COLOR_PICKER_VERSION = '1.5'
    final BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = '8.8.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
    compile "com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the project gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `SNAPSHOT` for Android Studio 3.0 and above or  downgrade your `ButterKnife` to `8.4.0`:  `annotationProcessor`, `library`  and `plugin` which also works. Tested.

Comment: thanks  it works all what i have to do right now  is change '@bind' with '@bindView'

Comment: `@Bind` is replaced with `@BindView` in `ButterKnife 8.0.0` and above if you previous used one of the old versions like `7.*` then you need to replace `@Bind` with `@BindView` but if you didn't all remains same. Here are the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662171/what-is-the-difference-between-bind-and-bindview-in-butterknife